# XamarinForms AppCompat OnOptionsItemSelected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat, xamarin.forms

I have recently updated xamarin forms to 1.5.1-pre1 so that I can use the beautiful AppCompat themes. It works and looks very nice.

I do have one problem, in my old FormsApplicationActivity I used to override the OnOptionsItemSelected method to intercept when the user was clicking on the back arrow icon and do some viewmodel cleanup. Apparently this method is not being called after using the FormsAppCompatActivity. 
How can I intercept the "soft" back button press (toolbar icon not hard back button) ?

I also tried to override the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer but i can't seem to override it :(

Does anyone have a clue how I can intercept this?

Comment: Why not `OnDisappearing()`?

Comment: Thanks, OnDisappearing works for celaning up vm stuff, I had to take care to clean it up only when it was going to be popped from the stack. But it's still not clear why the other methods (on options item selected) are not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the last two lines of the OnCreate() After adding them OnOptionsItemSelected was called as expected).

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UdaraAlwis/Xamarin-Playground/master/XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride/XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride/XFNavBarBackBtnClickOverride.Droid/MainActivity.cs

```
        Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Nice answer :) So that was the trick. I will mark this as the accepted answer. I did find a workaround back in 2015 for the project I was involved in, but it's good to know there is a "proper workaround" way of doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your custom renderer. You can either user [current activity plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) or cast your context to activity.

```
var toolbar = CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity?.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

toolbar.NavigationClick += ToolbarNavigationClick;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Forms there's a better way to intercept the NavigationBar back button pressed and the hardware back button pressed, which is creating your own `NavigationRenderer` and overriding the method `OnPopViewAsync`:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace YourApp.Droid
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomNavigationRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
        {
            // Write your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps